# Laravel request query dynamically from client

Tags: php, laravel

Recenlty I saw a website requesting data to server like this

[image]

so that I can get multiple data by multiple query at one.

[image]

can someone give me a clue way to execute like this request payload dynamically in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-input and see the "Retrieving Input From The Query String" header. I think it's what you're looking for.